# Hibernate Search: Find in list of intervals

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I am using Hibernate Search 6.x within my Spring Boot application. I got an indexed entity with a set of date intervals.

```
@Indexed
public class ProudParent {
   ...
   @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = {"start", "end"})
   Set<DateInterval> parentalLeaves;
}
```

And the class DateInterval looks like

```
@Embeddable
public class DateInterval {
    
    @GenericField
    LocalDate start;

    @GenericField
    LocalDate end;
}
```

That is my range query to search for all proud parents which were in parental leave on a specific `date`:

```
bool.must(factory.range().field("parentalLeaves.start").lessThan(date));
bool.must(factory.range().field("parentalLeaves.end").greaterThan(date));
```

Now the problem is that it finds proud parents which first parental leave was before `date` and the last parental leave was after `date`. So it does not search in the "same" date interval.

Can someone give me a hint of what I'm doing wrong?

Regards, Rokko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@IndexedEmbedded` will "flatten" the object structure by default, so all starts and ends are mixed together in the index, with no way to know which end matches which start.

You can read more about this [in this section of the reference documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded-structure). In short, this default is mainly for performance, because preserving the object structure can be (very) costly on large indexes, and is *usually* not necessary.

The solution, in your case, would be to use a `NESTED` structure:

```java
@Indexed
public class ProudParent {
   ...
   @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = {"start", "end"}, structure = ObjectStructure.NESTED)
   Set<DateInterval> parentalLeaves;
}
```

Then make sure to tell Hibernate Search you want the matches on `start` and `end` to be on the same `parentalLeave`, using a [`nested` predicate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-nested):

```java
bool.must(factory.nested().objectField("parentalLeaves") 
        .nest(factory.bool()
                .must(factory.range()
                        .field("parentalLeaves.start")
                        .lessThan(date)) 
                .must(factory.range()
                        .field("parentalLeaves.end")
                        .greaterThan(date)))
```

Don't forget to reindex your data before testing.

---

Side note: the syntax should be slightly more convenient with the upcoming Hibernate Search 6.2.0.Alpha2 (not yet released):

```java
bool.must(factory.nested("parentalLeaves") 
        .add(factory.range()
                .field("parentalLeaves.start")
                .lessThan(date)) 
        .add(factory.range()
                .field("parentalLeaves.end")
                .greaterThan(date)))
```

---

Other side note: hopefully one day we'll have date ranges as a primitive type in Hibernate Search ([HSEARCH-4199](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4199)) and this whole discussion will become irrelevant :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked great! Do you mean that this solution is (very) costly on index size or query duration?

Comment: Probably both, though you're unlikely to see the difference on small indexes (say, less than 100,000 documents? IDK). Anyway, just see for yourself: if you don't see a problem, then there's no problem.

Comment: One more question about that: Searching works great for us, but when I create a projection for this nested IndexedEmbedded field, I get randomly data of other entities as well. In older Hibernate Search versions (< 6) you mentioned that projection of IndexedEmbedded fields does not work, but in Hibernate Search 6 this warning in the documentation is gone and it seems to work at least for non nested IndexedEmbedded fields. Do you have a hint what I should be aware of?

Comment: @Rokko_11 I'll need some code to understand. Please submit another question with more details, in particular the code you use when projecting?

Comment: It looks like I have the problem described in HSEARCH-3943. I guess I just implement a workaround until I upgrade to 6.2 (or I convince the team to use the Alpha version ;-) )